# Recursive counting in arbitrary nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, flatten

I'm attempting to do some data visualization and dealing with this dataset. Object with arbitrary nested objects. I'm trying to count how many times different values appear in a key. This is just a snippet of the dataset, in the original the `owns` nested objects go 7+ levels deep.

**Example dataset I'm working with:**

```
var companyData = [{
    company: 'Pepsico',
    type: 'parent',
    owns: [
      {
      company: 'Cheetos',
      type: 'chips',
      owns: [{
        company: 'CheezyChipCo',
        type: 'chips',
        owns: []
      }]
      },
      {
        company: 'Gatorade',
        type: 'drink',
        owns: [{
          company: 'Powerade',
          type: 'drink',
          owns: []
        }]
        },
    ],
  }];
```

I'm thinking I'll have to do a Recursion or a Flatten type operation. So I can put all the `type` values into an array like this.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
[ 'drink', 'drink', 'chips', 'chips', 'parent' ]
```

I need to open up `owns` so I can properly count the `type` values. I feel like there are two ways I can go about it. Either recursion to go deep into an object. OR flatten the objects, so that all the nests are on the same level. I'll probably use `Object[keys]` in combination with `.filter`, `.some`, or `.reduce`. But I am so stumped on how and in what order, and would love some help! Here's my psuedo:

1. if (type of object's key is an Object)
2. && if (object's key === "type")
3. then push that type.value to an array
4. else if (type of object's key !=== object)
5. then just return the new sorted array

Sorry, real frontend dev hours. I don't know if that made sense and if posting all my failed code attempts would help.

Comment: In your desired output you will lose the information of the "ownership" relationship, as clearly the "drink" does not have such a relationship with "chips", yet the output does not show you this. Are you sure it is *that* output you need??

Comment: Yeah in this case, the relational data is not a big deal, since only dealing with one parent i.e. Pepsico. The intended dataviz are multicolor dots (i.e. green for chips, blue for drinks). I have an array count function rdy 2 go. I can definitely see the relational data being needed for like :hover if you wanna see a who owns what company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using straightforward recursion...

```js
var companyData = [{ company: 'Pepsico', type: 'parent', owns: [{ company: 'Cheetos', type: 'chips', owns: [{ company: 'CheezyChipCo', type: 'chips', owns: [] }] }, { company: 'Gatorade', type: 'drink', owns: [{ company: 'Powerade', type: 'drink', owns: [] }] },], }];

function mapTypes(arr, acc = []) {
  for (const o of arr) {
    acc.push(o.type);
    if (o.owns.length > 0) {
      acc = mapTypes(o.owns, acc)
    }
  }
  return acc;
}

console.log(mapTypes(companyData));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple recursive `flatten` -

```js
const flatten = ({ type, owns = [] }) =>
  [ type, ...owns.flatMap(flatten) ]
 
const input =
  [{company:'Pepsico',type:'parent',owns:[{company:'Cheetos',type:'chips',owns:[{company:'CheezyChipCo',type:'chips',owns:[]}]},{company:'Gatorade',type:'drink',owns:[{company:'Powerade',type:'drink',owns:[]}]}]}]
 
console.log(input.flatMap(flatten))
```

```json
[
  "parent",
  "chips",
  "chips",
  "drink",
  "drink"
]
```

Comment: wow .flatMap is so clean, thanks Thank you haha. I ran this with a performance.now() test and it runs at an average 0.1 - 0.7ms. Will defs try out w/ a larger dataset

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You can do it with a reduce function.

```js
var companyData = [{
    company: 'Pepsico',
    type: 'parent',
    owns: [
      {
      company: 'Cheetos',
      type: 'chips',
      owns: [{
        company: 'CheezyChipCo',
        type: 'chips',
        owns: []
      }]
      },
      {
        company: 'Gatorade',
        type: 'drink',
        owns: [{
          company: 'Powerade',
          type: 'drink',
          owns: []
        }]
        },
    ],
  }];

    let arr = []
const formattedData = (data) => data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   arr.push(curr.type);
  
  if (Array.isArray(curr.owns)) {
    formattedData(curr.owns)
  }
  
  return arr;
  
}, []);
  
 console.log(formattedData(companyData))
```

Comment: Thanks HichamELBSI! I ran your function with a performance.now() test and it runs at a speed of 0.03ms (w/the example dataset). Compared to the others, this one is currently the fastest.

Comment: Actually, running this on an array of length 1000 iterating 1000 times comes out at an average of 0.09ms with simple recursion coming in at 0.06ms and poor flatMap limping over the line with 2.01ms (each run independently in clean consoles on Chrome)

Comment: Dang truu!  Ever so trusty for loops, thanks 4 ur for loop solution pilchard